# Large HTTP Response Stream

Tags: c#, .net, json, stream

I'm trying to send a serialized object (formerly a List of Objects):

```
string objectsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);
```

as a HTTP response by using this code:

```
using (Stream stream = context.Response.OutputStream)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(objectsJson);
            }
        }
```

and it works great up to 1020 chars (or in my terms: 3 objects). When I'm trying to send 4 objects or more, it sends only the first 1020 chars and I'm missing the rest of the information.

How can I modify this code section so that it will support more than 3 objects?

Comment: Have you tried to writer.Flush() after writer.Write() ?

Comment: Yep, doesn't work..